# Como actualizar las variables de $_SESSION

Tags: php, mysql, html5

Cuando se cambie algo en la base de datos quiero que se cambie también en la web

intento usar una funcion() ejemplo:

```
function actualizar_datos(){
   //Contenido para actualizar las variables de $_SESSION['']
   $_SESSION['nombre'] = $VARIBLE_HOST;
   $_SESSION['email'] = $VARIABLE_HOST;
}
```

Comment: Sí quieres que se "active" , invocarla  es el proceso es decir `actualizar_datos();` o si está dentro de una clase `$this->actualizar_datos()`

Comment: Cuando haces un login las variables se guardan, pero quiero que al reiniciar la pagina se actualicen los datos guardados en $_SESSION

Comment: ¿Qué variables? ¿Qué proceso de login?, como menciono en mi primer comentario si desea que se actualicen los datos como tiene en su función , debe llamar a dicha función .  Más de eso, no es posible entender al menos para mi que pretende hacer.

Comment: Hola, falta información, estrictamente estás respondiendo a la pregunta con el ejemplo que adjuntas. Realmente haciendo `$_SESSION['nombre']=$VARIABLE_HOST;` estás actuaizando el valor de las variables de sesión. Como dice @Dev.Joel es dificil entender donde tienes la duda.

Comment: Si haces $_SESSION['nombre'] = $VARIBLE_HOST; para guardar el valor, entonces puedes hacer echo $_SESSION['nombre']; para mostrarlo, es decir, para actualizar la página con los datos al momento de recargarla, solo tienes que volcar el contenido de dichas variables al html.